# Fabric. A string as an argument to the command

Tags: java, minecraft-fabric

I need to get a string as a command argument.

I am trying to get a string as a command argument in the following way:

```
CommandRegistrationCallback.EVENT.register((dispatcher, dedicated) -> {
    dispatcher.register(CommandManager.literal("cmd_name")
     .then(RequiredArgumentBuilder.argument("msg", StringArgumentType.greedyString()))
     .executes(context -> {
        String message = StringArgumentType.getString(context, "msg");
        System.out.println(message);
        return 1;
    })
     .executes(context -> {
        System.out.println("ff");
        return 1;
      }));
});
```

This works fine with a command without a parameter, but refuses to work when I add a parameter.
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD1tE.png)